# how to take url parameters from AWS API Gateway and input them into lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have setup my API gateway and hooked it up to my lambda function

I set the url to {id} and want to pass this parameter into the lambda,

However even after trying multiple intergration requests using the default template and a custom one , the lambda still cant detect the paramters passed in the api gateway (id)

Ive tried assigning id to different parameters in my node js lambda function mapping it to path.params.id and other variables even tried the string query but it still isnt being detected in the lambda any ideas?

Comment: Can you share more details? For example the mapping template?

Comment: Do you pass it to a custom authorizer lambda before your business logic lambda?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example lambda function that pulls out an `id` path parameter:

```
module.exports.get = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { id } = event.pathParameters;
  console.log("id", id); 
};
```

You can also get query string parameters with `event.queryStringParameters`.

A detailed example can be found in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).

Comment: How should the `event` parameter be typed when using TypeScript? There seems to be multiple options such as `APIGatewayEvent` and `APIGatewayProxyEvent`. I'm encountering issues where the `id` cannot be destructured from `event.pathParameters`.